# Co-pilot suddenly missing and not working in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I have been using Github Copilot successfuly in VSCode for python scripts and within jupyter notebooks for the past week until today when it stopped working. The "activate icon" no longer appears in the bottom right hand corner, in-line suggestions no longer appear, and when I go to Output, Github Copilot is no longer in the drop-down menu.

I have tried:

- Uninstalling, restarting, and re-installing the co-pilot extension
- Signing in and out of github
- Completely uninstalling/deleting VSCode and reinstalling

My free-trial has not expired. My VSCode is up-to-date.

When reinstalling the Github Copilot extension, I am no longer asked to authorize the extension.

I've tried searching the internet and trying everything I can find. Please help if you can.